# What is the difference between Function and AsyncFunction in Google Guava?

Tags: asynchronous, guava

Internally, Function and Async Function are both non-blocking (right?). So, why do we have  AsyncFunction. Is the difference only that one returns a ListenableFuture Object and the other returns the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well one of them deals with transforming an Iterable for example and one transforms (possibly asynchronously) from one ListenableFuture to another. The concepts are completely different and deal with different things.

Here is a small example of AsyncFunction, basically we asynchronously get a String and then asynchronously transform that String into a different one. This is just a sample though..

```
public class GuavaAsyncFunction {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService deletegate = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ExecutorService deletegateForAsyncFunction = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        ListeningExecutorService pool = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(deletegate);
        ListeningExecutorService poolForAsyncFunction = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(deletegateForAsyncFunction);
        ListenableFuture<String> resultFromWorker = pool.submit(new Worker());

        ListenableFuture<String> finalResult = Futures.transform(resultFromWorker, new AsyncTransformation(poolForAsyncFunction));

        Futures.addCallback(finalResult, new MyFutureCallback());

    }

    private static final class Worker implements Callable<String> {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            try {
                System.out.println("Executing in thread="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                //simultate some work
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
            } catch(InterruptedException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "CALCULATED_VALUE";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Almost like Function transformation but it is asynchronous
     */
    private static final class AsyncTransformation implements AsyncFunction<String, String> {

        private final ListeningExecutorService poolToRunFunctionIn;

        public AsyncTransformation(ListeningExecutorService poolToRunFunctionIn){
            this.poolToRunFunctionIn = poolToRunFunctionIn;
        }

        public ListenableFuture<String> apply(String input) throws Exception {
            return poolToRunFunctionIn.submit(new FunctionWorker(input));
        }

        /**
         * 'worker' for the AsyncFunction
         */
        private static final class FunctionWorker implements Callable<String> {
            private final String input;
            public FunctionWorker(String input){
                this.input = input;
            }
            public String call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Executing in thread="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                } catch(InterruptedException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return input + "_TRANSFORMED";
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * what do to when the ListenableFuture has been processed
     */
    private static final class MyFutureCallback implements FutureCallback<String> {
        public void onSuccess(String result) {
            System.out.println("Result from computation = " + result);
        }

        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspected this is how it worked. thanks for confirming my suspicions.